# Какой тег подходит для сравнение тега и листа

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pip, процесс

У меня есть список и переменная которою мне надо сравнить со списком с помощью библиотеки `fuzzywuzzy`. какой fuzzy тег в данном случае нужно использовать?

````
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Оброшение
alias = ['арка', 'ара', 'арара', 'аришенька', 'арочка'] # оброшение (для удаления)
tbr = ['скажи', 'расскажи', 'сказать'] # Просьба сказать (для удаления)
cname = ['зовут', 'название', 'прозвище',]# имя
csearch = ['найди', 'загугли', 'поиск', 'подскажи', 'найдика', 'найди в интернете'] # поиск
# Время
ctime = ['время', 'час'] # время
ctimer = ['таймер', 'засеки', 'засеки время']#таймер
csleep = ['засни', 'усни', 'засыпай', 'отключись'] # отключение на время
# Приложения
calc = ['сколько будеть', 'сколько', 'посчитай', 'сложи', 'умнож', 'раздели', 'вычти'] # калькулятор
a = 'Как тебя зовут'

for x in alias:
    fuzAlias = fuzz.WRatio(x, a)
    print(fuzAlias)
    if fuzAlias >= 60:
        aliasT = True
        pass
    else:
        aliasT = False


for x in tbr:
    fuzTbr = fuzz.WRatio(x, a)
    print(fuzTbr)
    if fuzTbr >= 60:
        tbrT = True
        pass
    else:
        tbrT = False


for x in ctime:
    fuzCtime = fuzz.WRatio(x, a)
    print(fuzCtime)
    if fuzCtime >= 60:
        ctimeT = True
        pass
    else:
        ctimeT = False


for x in cname:
    fuzCname = fuzz.WRatio(x, a)
    print(fuzCname)
    if fuzCname >= 60:
        cnameT = True
        pass
    else:
         cnameT = False
print (aliasT)
print (tbrT)
print (ctimeT)
print (cnameT) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поменяйте везде в вашем коде `pass` на `break` и тогда у вас произойдёт "опознание" слова 'зовут' в списке `cname`.

`pass` - это слово-заполнитель, "пустая команда"

`break` - прерывает исполнение цикла

В вашем коде цикл не прерывался и последующие сравнения просто "затирали" положительный результат опознания слова из списка.